# How to simulate "Control + Space" in protractor test cases?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor, automated-tests

We have a scenario in our project - there is a text area in which if we click "ctrl + space", there is a list/dropdown which gets visible. Now I want to simulate this behaviour with my protractor test case.

Please find the code below:

```
await letterBody.sendKeys(lettertestdata.LetterTemplate.letterBodyText); // to enter "this is automated test text"
await letterBody.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SPACE));
```

2nd line of the code snippet is not working. It enters a space (blank space character) instead of ctrl+space behaviour. Although
if I write `await letterBody.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"))` , it selects the whole text.

Basically ctrl + A is working but ctrl + space is not.

Can someone please help how to fix it.

P.S. I have tried all combinations of using " " instead of Key.Space OR using keydown with Control and then sendKeys with SPACE and " " etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Protractor just sends a literal space character with its `Key.SPACE`.
Tried using the [Unicode for the SPACE key](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d943ee2950e25a2f4a3492058107cfd005d6f7fd/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js#L44) by `element.sendKeys("\uE00D")` and still didn't work.

I suggest you try executing a javascript event `dispatchEvent` on the element.

E.x:

```
    const ctrlSpace = 
       `var input = document.querySelector("input#'letter body']");                       

        input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key: "", ctrlKey: true}));
        input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {key: "", ctrlKey: true}));`

    await browser.executeScript(ctrlSpace);
```

It may seem "hacky" but I don't think there's another way around to your problem.